# Java DataInputStream read does not return

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, blocking

I am implementing a simple client/server reader and I am using DataInputStream to read everything as bytes, and then take care of the parsing later.

So this is my reading code:

```
String line;
String requestString = "";

//client is a Socket that is initialized elsewhere
DataInputStream inputData = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
byte [] messageByte = new byte[1024];
int counter = 0;
  while(true) {  
    int bytesRead = inputData.read(messageByte, counter, 1024-counter);
    counter = (counter + bytesRead)%1024;
    if(bytesRead == -1) {
      System.out.println("Breaking out of loop");
      break;
    }
    line = new String(messageByte, 0, bytesRead);
    System.out.println( "GOT > " + line );
  }
```

It is able to read the messages, but can't break out of the loop because the last call to read doesn't return.

Comment: You will get -1 as a result of your `read` call only when you reach the end of the stream. In case of sockets this means that the other side has to close connection.

Comment: What's the purpose of `counter`? It seems like it serves no purpose and makes your code harder to understand. You could replace `int bytesRead = inputData.read(messageByte, counter, 1024-counter);` with `int bytesRead = inputData.read(messageByte, 0, messageByte.length);`

Comment: Can you use `available()` in your case?

Comment: @Progman available is not a good option, there is latecy on the network. The fact that there is no available input now, does not mean there will not be later.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Then what is the problem that this call is blocking when you expect that it does not block?

Comment: @Progman he expects that the stream will end at one point and he will know when the stream has ended. The stream may end either due to no more input which is defined by no more input in certain timeframe, or alternativly because something has happened on the network and the stream returns -1. The purpose of the available() method is that while you are waiting for more input you might actualy in the same thread do something else usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets will block until there is no more input. InputStream is just an interface exact behaviour depends on its provider implementation. Set timeout on your socket so that exception is thrown if there is no input in certain period.

Here is quotation from [javadoc on Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout-int-), notice that it describes the behaviour of the read from a socket as blocking operation until a timeout is reached:

> ```
> public void setSoTimeout(int timeout)
>                   throws SocketException
> ```
>
> Enable/disable `SO_TIMEOUT` with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a
>   non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with
>   this Socket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout
>   expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the
>   Socket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering
>   the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A
>   timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

The solution:

Besides checking for -1 which is OK. Set timeout on the socket and ensure the exception when thrown is processed correctly.

Comment: Will this ensure that I will get everything in the stream? I was thinking of another approach that states if the bytes read is not equal to the size of the buffer then break indicating that the read has reached the end of the stream. is that a safe approach as well? If you still recommend the time out what would be an acceptable amount of time?

Comment: I don't think it is a good aproach. You have a message that you send over the socket and most probably it has a fixed size. I don't see how you can get a different amount of bytes  unless your messages are of different size.

Comment: My thought was if a message is bigger than say `BUF_SIZ` , it will first read in `BUF_SIZ` amount and if its at the end of the message, it will read less than `BUF_SIZ`. But I do see an issue where if the message size is some multiple of `BUF_SIZ`. As far as the time out amount, what is a reasonable time to allow for the data stream to come in

Comment: I don't think there is any specific number that is recoommended it depends on the application requirements. But you don't want to keep the connection open too long as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I selected your response as the answer